# Chrome devtools pretty printer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

One of the minified javascript files are not pretty printed ("formatted") in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Devtools pretty printer is "delete" keyword sensitive. 
For example `map.delete(...)` will break the pretty printer function.
In this case use `map["delete"](...)`